# faster adb commands (skip delay in each command)

Tags: android, adb

I send debug commands via adb in windows to my rooted android device.
command is in a loop:

`adb shell input tap 200 200`

but it seems there is a second or fewer delay in each command to run in device.
is there any way to send commands on device without delay or decrease it?

Note: I used tasker and result was same as adb in windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delay between "type" commands in AdbClient (which doesn't exist in monkeyrunner)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963237/delay-between-type-commands-in-adbclient-which-doesnt-exist-in-monkeyrunner)

Comment: Please check this link. This will record touches and can do a play back. Play back speed will exactly same as recording. This will send touches via custom `sendevent` instead of `adb shell input`. https://github.com/rils/ARP/wiki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no delay "between" the commands. It just takes about a second (depending on the device) to run the `input` command.